# Simple integral with min function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $T_j>T_{j-1}$. 
I'm looking at the solution of the integral:

$$\int_t^{T_j} \min\left\{ \frac{T_j-s}{T_j-T_{j-1}},1\right\}\ (T_j-s)ds$$

the solution for $t>T_{j-1}$ is given as $$\frac13(T_j-t)^2$$
but in my opinion the solution is wrong.

What I find is instead $$\frac13 \frac{(T_j-t)^3}{T_j-T_{j-1}}$$
am i missing something or the given solution is wrong?

Comment: The integral is $ds$?

Comment: yes, sorry @BenedictW.J.Irwin

Comment: yours looks right to me